error installing software into my environment in my jupyter notebook
my problem is that I am running this code to create an environment !conda create -y -n phage_od python=3.9 ipykernel, and after doing that I wanted to install the software I need for my bioinformatic analysis, using the following commands...
!mamba install -y trim-galore 

...for this command I am getting the error-

Could not solve for environment specs Encountered problems while
solving:- package trim-galore-0.4.1-0 requires cutadapt, but none of
the providers can be installed. The environment can't be solved,
aborting the operation

however when i try and install cut adapt i then get another error..

Could not solve for environment specs
Encountered problems while solving:- package
cutadapt-4.2-py39hbf8eff0_0 requires xopen >=1.6.0, but none of the
providers can be installed. The environment can't be solved, aborting
the operation

!mamba install -y pilon

...This command works fine
!mamba install -y spades

...This command works fine
!mamba install -y pharokka

...This command also gives me a similar error- Could not solve for environment specs

Encountered problems while solving:- package
pharokka-1.7.0-pyhdfd78af_0 requires biopython >=1.80,<1.82, but none
of the providers can be installed. The environment can't be solved,
aborting the operation

!mamba install -y samtools

...This command works fine
!mamba install -y minimap2

...This command works fine
!mamba install -y clinker-py

..This command gives me a similar error...
when i run my first command- to create an environment using !conda create -y -n phage_od python=3.9 ipykernel, It runs but I am getting this message

SafetyError: The package for ca-certificates located at
/shared/team/conda/pkgs/ca-certificates-2024.2.2-hbcca054_0 appears to
be corrupted. The path 'ssl/cacert.pem' has an incorrect size.reported
size: 292541 bytes actual size: 0 bytes

so not sure whether this is linked to the installation issues I am having as stated above :)
Tried what I stated above

Welcome to stackoverflow! Please do familiarize yourself with the editing tools when you post. You can also read up on Stackoverflow Markdown so that your questions and answers don't show up as a wall of text.

If you are going to do installs from in the running .ipynb file, you should use %conda install , see here. (I believe that would also be %conda create..., too. I think.) The magic variation insures that the installation occurs in the environment where the kernel in Jupyter is actually running. The exclamation point can be a problem for installs, see here. You can maybe use some of those suggestions to work around %mamba install...

 not yet being implemented. See more about the modern magic install commands here. The second paragraph here goes into more details about why the exclamation point may lead to issues. Note that this isn't guaranteed to help in any way with your issues reported here; however, you'll have a better experience in Jupyter using current best practices.
